# Showing two matrices have the same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

> Show that the matrices  $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ have the same minimal polynomials.

Is it correct to say the characteristic polynomials of the two are ($x-2$)($x+1$$)^3$ and ($x-2$$)^3$($x+1$) respectivly and the minimal polynomials are ($x-2)(x+1$) since that's the irreducible factorization of both?

Comment: I guess you meant $(x-2)(x+1)$ ; that is indeed the minimal polynomial of both matrices but not because "it's the irreducible factorization of both".

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it. I thought the minimal polynomial was the minimal polynomial that divided the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Well then why wouldn't it be, say, $(x-2)$ ? Be sure to know the definition : the minimal polynomial $m_A$ of $A$ is the monic polynomial of last degree that divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$, that shares the same root with it, and such that $m_A(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ is the smallest *monic* polynomial $p$ (by degree) such that $p(A) = 0$. So you suspect that $(x-2)(x+1) = x^2 -x -2$ is the minimal polynomial of each of those matrices (say name them $A$ and $B$). One way to check that would be to

1. Calculate $A^2$ and $B^2$, and check that $ A^2 -A -2 = 0$ and $ B^2 -B -2 = 0$
2. Make a brief argument that a linear polynomial cannot be the minimal polynomial of either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Small remark : it is the smallest **monic** polynomial such that...

Comment: Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

we know that the dimension of the eigen space: $dim(E_\lambda)=n-rank(A-\lambda I)$, for a $n\times n$ matrix $A$. So $dim(E_{-1})=4-rank(A+ I)=3$. So the number of Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $=3$. Since algebraic multiplicity of $-1$  is $3$, so highest order Jordan block of $-1$ is $1$. Similarly for the eigenvalue $2$ highest order Jordan block is $1$. So the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(t)=(t+1)(t-2)$.

Also for the matrix $B$, $dim(E_{-2})=4-rank(A+ 2I)=3$ and by same reason  $m_B(t)=(t+1)(t-2)$. Although their characteristic polynomial are different.

Comment: This is killing a fly with a bazooka...